# Count number of Facebook Friends of a user

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

For an Android app I need to get number of Facebook Friends of the users when he logged in to the app using Facebook profile. I went through few question in Stackoverflow but no success. I'll be really grateful if someone can come up with an idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a FQL query that will give count of friends list for a particular user based on id. Try hitting below link
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()%0A.

Answer (score 1):

> The Facebook SDK provides a FriendPickerFragment class that displays a
>   list of friends for a user. You'll host this fragment in a new
>   activity. The activity you define will be used when a friend or place
>   is selected. You'll launch the activity when the user clicks on a
>   friend or place picker item. You'll set up the activity and show the
>   relevant fragment based on incoming intent data.
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends/